# Chartjs: Align first tick in first index of axis

Tags: jquery, json, chart.js

I'm trying to show usage in chartjs time scale, with a date range. But somethimes, the data are extensive (350+). In that cases, the start of y-axis grid lines is not align with the first tick of x-axis. I have searched for solution, but people say that they have already solved this. Why this still ocurs with me?
[image]
I'm using the latest chartjs version (2.6), and the code similar as the follow.

```
var config= {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'CPU',
                fill: true,
                pointHitRadius: 25,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scaleBeginAtZero: false,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Uso de CPU'
            },
            hover: {animationDuration: 100},
            layout:{
                padding: {left: 50, right: 50, top: 50, bottom: 50 }
            },
            legend:{display: false },
            animation: {duration: 500 },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    ticks: {
                        maxRotation: 0,
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 12,
                        bounds: "data",
                    },
                    time: {
                        round: 'minutes',
                        displayFormats: {
                            'millisecond': 'HH:mm',
                            'second': 'HH:mm',
                            'minute': 'HH:mm',
                            'hour': 'HH:mm',
                            'day': 'DD [de] MMM [de] YY',
                            'week': 'DD [de] MMM [de] YY',
                            'month': 'DD [de] MMM [de] YY',
                            'quarter': 'DD [de] MMM [de] YY',
                            'year': 'DD [de] MMM [de] YY',
                        },
                        tooltipFormat: 'D MMM YYYY H:mm'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        stepSize: 25,
                        suggestedMin: 0,
                        suggestedMax: 100,
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value+"% ";
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };
    var rows = {"rows":[{"x":"2017-08-25T10:16:54-03:00","y":21}]}; //continues 350+
    var canvas = $('<canvas>', {id: element});
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
    window.myChart.data.datasets[0].data = rows;
    window.myChart.update();
```

Any help will be apreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched and found no answers. I went back to [the documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source) and checked all available options. I have solved this with the options: `scales.xAxes.distribution: 'series'` (can be linear), `scales.xAxes.source: 'auto'` and `scales.bounds: 'ticks'`

Comment: thank you very much. setting `distribution` property solved similar issue for me.